# CreateSprocAccessor parameter issue with DB2

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, parameters, db2, enterprise-library

I'm using Enterprise Library 5.0 and can get the CreateSqlStringAccessor to work fine with a custom parameter mapper, but I get:
ERROR [42884] [IBM][DB2] SQL0440N  No authorized routine named "MySchema.MySPName" of type "" having compatible arguments was found.  SQLSTATE=42884

CreateSprocAccessor Code:

```
var database = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Database>("MyDataSource");
var storedProcAccessorCommand = database.CreateSprocAccessor<ObjectResult>("MySchema.MySPName", new PersonKeyParameterMapper());
var searchResult = storedProcAccessorCommand.Execute("123456");
var rowCount = searchResult.Count();
```

CreateSqlStringAccessor Code:

```
var database = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Database>("MyDataSource");
var command = database.CreateSqlStringAccessor<ObjectResult>("select FirstName, LastName, MiddleName from MySchema.MyTable where PersonKey = @PersonKey", new PersonKeyParameterMapper());
var searchResult = command.Execute("123456");
var rowCount = searchResult.Count();
```

ObjectResult:

```
public class ObjectResult
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

PersonKeyParameterMapper Code:

```
public class PersonKeyParameterMapper : IParameterMapper
{
    public void AssignParameters(DbCommand command, object[] parameterValues)
    {
        var personKey = command.CreateParameter();
        personKey.ParameterName = "@PersonKey";
        personKey.DbType = DbType.String;
        personKey.Value = parameterValues[0];
        command.Parameters.Add(personKey);
    }
}
```

DB2 Stored Proc Interface:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MySchema.MySPName (  
    IN PersonKey VARCHAR(9)
)
```

I've read up that ParameterMappers are required for DB2, but not sure why it's working for SqlString and not Sproc. I tried passing the parameter as "@PersonKey" and as just "PersonKey", neither work. Thanks.